# how to change 2d bar chart into 3d bar chart using d3.js and angular

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angular7

I am using d3.js to render 3D bar chart.
I am able to render a normal 2d chart but 3d chart rendering is very difficult. I found some sample code to make svg rectangles as 3d.
Finally i want to apply changes to 2d bar chart but those changes are not working.

please find 2d bar chart below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-charts-lqchcx?file=app%2Fshared%2Fd3%2Fvbarchart2-filter1%2Fvbarchart2-filter1.component.ts

please find below link to make simple bar into 3d bar

(jsfiddle.net/d7aos9og/2/)
by using above two examples i would like to show the chart as in the image
[image: sample 3d barchart]

Please let me know how to do it. Very Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to get some inspiration from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/austinhyde/02a038074dbd9a7b1eb3)

Comment: @RubenHelsloot Thanks a lot for your comment but i want to implement it in angular so i am getting some confusion. if you have any examples of 3d barcharts(Opensource) Please share me

Comment: If you already have a 2d bar chart, then you should only have to update the rendering logic. In theory, you shouldn't have to do much angular-related things from now on